# Validate contacts in SurveyGizmo

Tags: survey

What I am going to do is to integrate SurveyGizmo with our User Management System.
We encourage our customer to finish survey or quiz on SurveyGizmo with credentials stored in our own database which could be validated by http requests.

However, I have no idea that how does SurveyGizmo handle the http response.
For example, if return true, continue the survey otherwise display an error message.

Anyone who can give me suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's impossible to utilize the individual password of SurveyGizmo, I didn't find any API to generate that or fetch generated password.  So I decide to create individual password in our own system, and use [HTTP Post](http://www.surveygizmo.com/survey-software-support/tutorials/http-connect-post-or-get-data-to-external-webpages/) provided by SG to validate the password in our system.  The response of the request will be stored in a hidden value.  A redirect action will check that value to decide which page will be shown next.